# Are push-ups beneficial for alleviating sagging breasts?

Tags: medical-science, physical-fitness

From here: http://www.livestrong.com/article/98061-benefits-pushups-women/

> Chest muscles also receive a workout during push-ups **and can help to
>   alleviate sagging breasts.**

From: http://www.livestrong.com/article/15977-home-remedies-sagging-breasts/

> Step 4
>   Perform push-ups. Either do the standard push-up in which the
>   entire body raises into the air or do the modified push-up in which
>   the knees are bent and only the upper portion of the body comes up off
>   the floor. Start with as many push-ups as you can comfortably do;
>   gradually increase the amount in each session. Do push-ups at least
>   three times a week.

Have any researches been done on these claims?

Comment: Push ups aren't going to anything to the breast tissue itself, but putting a saggy bag of tissue on a firm foundation has got to be better than the same saggy blob of tissue on a saggy foundation...

Answer (score 3):

The degree of female breast ptosis or sagging (woman's breast rate droop) depends on key factors such as cigarette smoking, number of pregnancies, gravity, higher body mass index, larger bra cup size, and significant weight gain and loss.

**Per study by Rinker B et. al. in 2010, lack of regular upper body exercise was not found to be a significant risk factor for [ptosis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20354434).**

> Upon logistic regression, age, history of significant (>50 lbs) weight loss, higher body mass index, larger bra cup size, number of pregnancies, and smoking history were found to be significant risk factors for breast ptosis (P < 0.05). History of breast-feeding, weight gain during pregnancy, and lack of participation in regular upper body exercise were not found to be significant risk factors for ptosis.

Comment: Depends on gravity? You mean that breasts drop differently on other planets?

Comment: The size of the breast and gravity can pull down the skin and ligaments in heavy breasts since they are composed of milk glands/ducts, fat, connective tissue, and Cooper’s ligaments. Fibers can stretch or break and cause sagging and pain throughout life or in vigorous exercise. During the beginning of a running stride, the breasts are found to accelerate at up to 3 G (where G is the force of gravity). This is considerably more than the rest of the trunk, and puts strain on Cooper’s ligaments. Breast mass was significantly correlated with vertical breast displacement.